# How view sections by id

Tags: variables, session, cakephp

I have database table called sections (id,name,keywords). I have section.ctp file want show on it the section which its

```
 $id =  $this->Session->read('secId');
```

but i don't know how do this on cakephp . Is it I need to  pass variables on sessions? .

in what file I should put sessions vairables

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable through set method in controller action not using session and you can use it in your view. You can use `cake bake` command to bake section controller, model and view. For more info how to use cake bake command, please visit [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)

Hope it helps. (vote and select the answer if it helps)